# Android Bluetooth Low energy Gatt Service implementation error

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, characteristics, bluetooth-gatt

I used android.bluetooth package in my project but i try to implement IBluetoothGatt for read and write characteristics. But i have some problems like below

```
public final class BluetoothGatt implements BluetoothProfile {
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothGatt";
    private static final boolean DBG = true;
    private static final boolean VDBG = false;

    private IBluetoothGatt mService;  // IBluetoothGatt red highlights. Some functions in IBluetoothGatt interface just work by put breakpoints.

    private BluetoothGattCallback mCallback;
    private int mClientIf;
    private boolean mAuthRetry = false;
    private BluetoothDevice mDevice;
    private boolean mAutoConnect;
    private int mConnState;
    private final Object mStateLock = new Object();
    private Boolean mDeviceBusy = false;
    private int mTransport;

    private static final int CONN_STATE_IDLE = 0;
    private static final int CONN_STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
    private static final int CONN_STATE_CONNECTED = 2;
    private static final int CONN_STATE_DISCONNECTING = 3;
    private static final int CONN_STATE_CLOSED = 4;

    private List<BluetoothGattService> mServices;
```

writeCharacteristic red highlights in IBluetoothGatt interface

```
public void onCharacteristicWrite(String address, int status, int handle) {
            if (VDBG) Log.d(TAG, "onCharacteristicWrite() - Device=" + address
                        + " handle=" + handle + " Status=" + status);

            if (!address.equals(mDevice.getAddress())) {
                return;
            }

            synchronized(mDeviceBusy) {
                mDeviceBusy = false;
            }

            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = getCharacteristicById(mDevice, handle);
            if (characteristic == null) return;

            if ((status == GATT_INSUFFICIENT_AUTHENTICATION
              || status == GATT_INSUFFICIENT_ENCRYPTION)
              && mAuthRetry == false) {
                try {
                    mAuthRetry = true;
                    mService.writeCharacteristic(mClientIf, address, handle,
                        characteristic.getWriteType(), AUTHENTICATION_MITM,
                        characteristic.getValue());
                    return;
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"",e);
                }
            }
```

Comment: what you exactly want to do

Comment: I want to communicate with ble device with writecharacteristic method. But writeCharacteristic method in Ibluetoothgatt interface(in android.bluetooth)  "cannot resolve" and I can not do this.

Comment: edit your code and write whole code of activity and service.
You need to scan and connect to device before writing data in ble.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i put breakpoint on some lines related to write characteristics, and debug step by step I write characteristics. Is problem in connecting with device? How can i edit?

Comment: make sure you are connecting to device and writing to device at the same time. BLE devices are slow to take multiple requests at the same time. so first connect to device and write the data in device connection success callback.

Comment: look at the below code

Answer (score 0):

use this article by it is very  useful .
[BLE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

Comment if you have any issue

Here is the code to connect to ble device.

```
public boolean connect(final String address)
{

    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
        return false;
    }
    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (device == null)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        return false;
    }
    // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
    // parameter to false.
    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion device is connected but I have same error in BluetothGatt.java just like definition IBluetoothGatt(red), clientConnect is red in IBluetoothGattCallback method and I can not write anything to device.

Comment: IBluetoothGatt is internal in Android and not part of the public API. You should therefore not open this file in your IDE. BluetoothGatt is also not a file you should open in your IDE. If you can't compile your project you should take another look at your SDK setup.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, IBluetoothGatt sources can be found at: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/android-5.0.2_r1/src/com/android/bluetooth/gatt/GattService.java#259

Android uses a system called Binder (an Android-specific IPC model) to separate user apps (i.e. the app you're writing) from system services that actually implement the functionality.  For most of the Android framework, the code is linked from your app "directly" with no need for the IPC bridge, which is why you're used to finding source code easily through your IDE.  For more advanced use cases where explicit process separation is important, they use the IPC bridge and will hide the functionality behind an auto-generated IPC interface created from an aidl file (usually that's ISomethingSomething and you can find an ISomethingSomething.aidl file in the main framework sources).  For example, [IBluetoothGatt.aidl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9908112/core/java/android/bluetooth/IBluetoothGatt.aidl).

The implementation of these aidl files is usually found in [frameworks/base/services](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/main/services/) or one of the frameworks/base/opt directories.
In Bluetooth's case it is located in one of the supplied [packages directories](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/).  The variation here is attributed to whether they want to be able to compose versions of Android with or without the APK.  For example, if they want to ship Android versions without Bluetooth support they can just omit the Bluetooth package APK to do so.

Looking through these sources is occasionally important as you'll find lots of surprising bugs or just wrong documentation this way, especially for bleeding edge APIs.